# Java generics type parameter confusion

Tags: java, generics

I've created a PriorityQueue which holds PeekingSortedIterators as follows:

```
PriorityQueue<PeekingSortedIterator<E>> pq= new PriorityQueue<>(iterators.size(), new IteratorComparator<E>());
pq.offer(new PeekingSortedIterator<E>(si));
```

The IteratorComparator compares the values underlying the PeekingSortedIterator. My code is as follows:

```
class IteratorComparator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparator<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>{ // note generics!!!
    @Override
    public int compare(PeekingSortedIterator<E> o1, PeekingSortedIterator<E> o2) {
        return o1.peek().compareTo(o2.peek());
    } 
 }
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Why is the type parameter for `IteratorComparator <E extends Comparable<E>>`  and not `<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>` since the class operates on `PeekingSortedIterator<E>`, not directly on E? I understand that if I did that, then I would need a different way to specify that E needs to extend Comparable, but I'm confused because with `IteratorComparator<E extends Comparable<E>>` it seems like the compare method should have been `compare(E e1, E e2)`.
2. Why is the IteratorComparator instance created with new `IteratorComparator<E>()`? Why do I get a compile time error (`Type mismatch: cannot convert from PriorityQueue<PeekingSortedIterator<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>> to PriorityQueue<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>`) if I modify it to `new IteratorComparator<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>()`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>` does not compile as a type parameter. Try to construct an example that does, and you will see why it is done this way.

Comment: So would it be more right to specify it as class `IteratorComparator<T extends PeekingSortedIterator<E>, E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparator<T>`? Even with that I cannot use `new IteratorComparator<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>()` since now the class needs 2 type params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand that `E` in `IteratorComparator<E extends Comparable<E>>` is not a concrete type but a type variable.

The line

```
class IteratorComparator<E extends Comparable<E>> 
    implements Comparator<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>{
```

declares a class `IteratorComparator` for some type `E` that is `Comparable<E>` (comparable to itself, for example `String` or `Integer`). This class implements `Comparator<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>`, meaning that it can compare two `PeekingSortedIterator<E>`s

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I guess my confusion is that if I need to specify `<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>` for Comparator, then why not for the class IteratorComparator, because all said and done it is the class that compares the 2  'PeekingSortedIterator's. Or is it that I don't need to specify `IteratorComparator<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>` because the compiler already knows that the class will operate on 'PeekingSortedIterator' because we've already specified that when we specified that the class implements Comparator which operates on `PeekingSortedIterator<E>`?

Comment: @TheWorldGoesRound by writing `implements Comparator<PeekingSortedIterator<E>>` you tell the compiler what kind of objects your class will compare (`PeekingSortedIterator<E>`). `PeekingSortedIterator<E>` itself has a type parameter `E` that you either need to specify (`PeekingSortedIterator<String>`) or have to declare on your class (`IteratorComparator<E>`)